# What is the name of this space museum in Russian and does it have a website and/or virtual tour site?

Tags: space-art, baikonur-cosmodrome, museum-exhibits

Enjoying the information and links in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32722/12102) I wanted to ask if these are real antennas now on display, or space art? But once I started clicking google maps I found that this is full blown space museum!

What is the name of this place *in English and Russian*, so that I could search further, and do they have an official website or virtual tour, or can I only do a "virtual visit" via google maps?

[Google maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Buran+.+Muzey+Kosmodroma+Baykonur./@45.9093262,63.3176707,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipPlg53lAHx0HK78VpyQ37oywUO2N1UxOYYXqZXZ!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPlg53lAHx0HK78VpyQ37oywUO2N1UxOYYXqZXZ%3Dw203-h135-k-no!7i3456!8i2304!4m5!3m4!1s0x41f44ec5e4591803:0xf094f806c1677115!8m2!3d45.9093255!4d63.3176704)

[image]

---

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images in the question are from the Buran museum. A number of photos can be found in the following blogpost: https://saidpvo.livejournal.com/679478.html

Here is a small sample:

[image: Buran Museum from saidpvo.livejournal.com/679478(dot)html]

[image: Buran Museum from saidpvo.livejournal.com/679478(dot)html]

[image: Buran Museum from saidpvo.livejournal.com/679478(dot)html]

Comment: Here's a question you might be able to help with: [How does this antenna work, with both a feed horn and hyperbolic secondary in front of the dish?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30717/12102)