# Why are modern satellite ground station and deep space communications dishes with secondary mirrors almost always Cassegrain?

Tags: communication, deep-space, deep-space-network, antenna

The simplest dish antennas have a concave reflector and their feed horns at the primary focus which is "up in the air".

That has several inconveniences, it's hard to go up there to do any kind of band or amplifier switching or add a liquid helium refrigerator for front-end cooling, much less repairs.

So bringing a secondary focus back down closer to the ground and often inside a large enclosure *behind* the dish has several advantages.

- [What is a Beam Waveguide dish and why do deep space communications stations use them?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49816/12102)

But as discussed in [this answer to *Schmidt corrector plate on a Newtonian = Schmidt Cassegrain?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/45233/7982) and all of the questions and answers linked therein, the main selling point of a Cassegrain telescope is its correction of [off-axis aberrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_aberration#Monochromatic_aberrations).

Except for some fancy radio astronomy imaging applications, most dish antennas are primarily on-axis power collectors for weak signals, especially in deep-space applications.

- (Astronomy.SE) [How do ASKAP's focal plane phased array feeds interact with the entire array phasing?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/21121/7982)
- (Astronomy.SE) [What is the highest granularity focal-plane array on a dish radio telescope? Or is this the ONLY ONE?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16237/7982)

**Question:** Why are modern satellite ground station and deep space large communications dishes with secondary mirrors almost always Cassegrain? Besides providing the folded path, are there ever situations where the off-axis aberration correction from the hyperbolic shape of the secondary provides additional benefits in performance, design or operation?

There are of course some notable exceptions!

- [How does this strangely-shaped horn at Honeysuckle Creek Tracking Station work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23153/12102)

Comment: just trying to clarify, are you asking why Cassegrain over a system with only a primary reflector or why Cassegrain over say Gregorian? (sorry, but StackExchange is eating my ATs again...)

Comment: @Grapefruit I don’t remember nor can I reconstruct my exact thinking now. I do point out that Cassegrains have off-axis corrections and wonder if those are ever taken advantage of, and I think that “besides folded path” means I’m not asking about secondary versus primary only. Does that help? Do you have an interesting answer that you think the wording currently excludes? I can edit if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer:**
The main benefits of the Cassegrain design for an antenna are lower loss, higher aperture efficiency, and more convenient location of the feed horn / low noise amplifier.

### Advantages of Cassegrain Design

- The feed radiator is more easily supported, and the antenna is geometrically compact ([The Cassegrain Antenna](https://www.radartutorial.eu/06.antennas/Cassegrain%20Antenna.en.html))
- It provides minimum losses as the receiver can be mounted directly near the horn ([The Cassegrain Antenna](https://www.radartutorial.eu/06.antennas/Cassegrain%20Antenna.en.html))
- Waveguide line is short resulting in less loss before the receiver ([Cassegrain feed-Function and basics of cassegrain](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/cassegrain-feed.html))
- Convenient location of the feed and active electronics ([Multiple Reflector Dish Antennas](http://www.w1ghz.org/antbook/conf/Multiple_reflector_antennas.pdf))
- Ability to customize the aperture illumination via the secondary reflector ([Multiple Reflector Dish Antennas](http://www.w1ghz.org/antbook/conf/Multiple_reflector_antennas.pdf))
- The Cassegrain type antenna has about 10% higher efficiency than the parabolic antenna with the same primary reflector size ([Study of Cassegrain-type antenna for radio telescope](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/2214/1/012028/pdf))
- The Cassegrain type antenna can also be operated in dual-frequency mode, has a lower noise system temperature, better pointing accuracy, and a more flexible feed design than parabolic antennas ([Study of Cassegrain-type antenna for radio telescope](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/2214/1/012028/pdf))

### Additional References

[Parabolic Reflector Antenna Feed Systems](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/antennas-propagation/parabolic-reflector-antenna/feeder-feed-systems.php) 
[LET’S TALK ABOUT REFLECTOR ANTENNAS](https://swamphen.co.uk/new-blog/2019/4/15/lets-talk-about-reflector-antennas) 
[A COMPARISON BETWEEN PRIME FOCUS AND CASSEGRAIN ANTENNAS](https://library.nrao.edu/public/memos/misc/MISC_UNUM_1064.pdf)